# Can't access properties of object after JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, rest

My function accepts a string containing a JSON object from a RESTful API.

For example: `"[{"user":"Nate A.","time":"2018-08-31T21:26:14.432Z"},{"user":"Nate A.","time":"2018-08-31T21:26:27.567Z"}]"`

I would like to loop through the objects in this array. So I do

```
var json = JSON.parse(string);
json.foreach(function(user) {
    console.log(user['time'];
}
```

When I console.log() the object, everything looks correct. But when I try to access the properties like `console.log(json.name)` or `console.log(json['name'])` I get `undefined`. I know for sure that I'm accessing the object after JSON.parse and not trying to get an attribute of the string. What gives?

```
var otherUsers = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    otherUsers.forEach(user => {
        console.log(user['name']); // undefined
        console.log(user.name); // undefined
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user)); // [{"user":"Nate A.","time":"2018-08-31T21:26:14.432Z"},{"user":"Nate A.","time":"2018-08-31T21:26:27.567Z"}]
    }
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: `user.user` perhaps? seeing as the JSON has no `name` property in it at all - only `user` and `time` property names in the JSON you posted

Comment: What's your actual code like? using JQuery gives me what you want.
`$.each(json, function(k,v) {
    console.log(v.user);
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment said you are trying to access the property `name` of the object but is does not exists.

```
for(user of json){
  console.log(user.user)
  console.log(user.time)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps, there is no name property, but your code is correct.

```js
var str = '[{"user":"Nate A.","time":"2018-08-31T21:26:14.432Z"},{"user":"Nate A.","time":"2018-08-31T21:26:27.567Z"}]'


var arr = JSON.parse(str);

arr.forEach(o => {
    console.log(o.name)//<-- undefined because there is no "name" property

    //both works 
    console.log(o.user)
    console.log(o['user'])

    console.log(o.time)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you declared your json object as a array (with []) - you should access the first place in the array,for example

```
json[0].user
```